# Why this jquery select doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

Let's say, for example, i have that code:

```
<form id="validate_form2">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input id="nome" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input id="phone" type="text">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

How can i change the TYPE from INPUT with ID='email' inside "VALIDATE_FORM2" form?

Comment: How do you mean change the type?

Comment: <input id="email" type="email"> by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with jquery - having to convert it back into a dom element

```
$('#email')[0].type = 'password';​​​​​​
// or using .prop $('#email').prop('type','password');​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/68ZPh/

or just plain js

```
document.getElementById('email').type = 'password';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tHWwZ/

As mentioned in the comments, this may cause issues in IE..

From jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) docs

> Note: jQuery prohibits changing the type attribute on an  or  element and will throw an error in all browsers. This is because the type attribute cannot be changed in Internet Explorer.

Another way would be to create a new input to replace it with

```
$('#email').replaceWith('<input type="password" id="email"/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uVXvk/

Comment: This may work, but the jQuery source reveals that "it causes problems in IE", and therefore they prevent it.